# Combining Qt Widgets and QML with QWidget::createWindowContainer()

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget, qt-quick

I've tried to follow this article:

http://www.ics.com/blog/combining-qt-widgets-and-qml-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer#.UlVUExCXcnI

If I try to redo this I get this error:

> 15:13:36: Running steps for project Test_QMLWidgets01...
>   15:13:36: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   15:13:36: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
>       C:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
>       cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtANGLE" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\VANBEB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.3328.0.jom
>   mainwindow.cpp
>   ..\Test_QMLWidgets01\mainwindow.cpp(2) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QQuickView': No such file or directory
>   jom: E:\QtProjects\build-Test_QMLWidgets01-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 2
>   jom: E:\QtProjects\build-Test_QMLWidgets01-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
>   15:13:36: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project Test_QMLWidgets01 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2010 32bit)
>   When executing step 'Make'
>   15:13:36: Elapsed time: 00:00.

So I changed #include  to #include  but then I get linking errors:

> 15:16:27: Running steps for project Test_QMLWidgets01...
>   15:16:27: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   15:16:27: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
>       C:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
>       cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtANGLE" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5\5.1.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\VANBEB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.4220.15.jom
>   mainwindow.cpp
>       echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.embed.manifest">debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe_manifest.rc
>       if not exist debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe if exist debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.embed.manifest del debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.embed.manifest
>       if exist debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.embed.manifest debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe_manifest.bak
>       link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe @C:\Users\VANBEB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe.4220.2886.jom
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void _*thiscall QQuickView::setSource(class QUrl const &)" (*_imp_?setSource@QQuickView@@QAEXABVQUrl@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QQuickView::QQuickView(class QWindow *)" (_*imp*??0QQuickView@@QAE@PAVQWindow@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QQuickView::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QQuickView@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QQuickView::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QQuickView@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QQuickView::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QQuickView@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QQuickWindow::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QQuickWindow@@MAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::timerEvent(class QTimerEvent *)" (?timerEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQTimerEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QAccessibleInterface * __thiscall QQuickWindow::accessibleRoot(void)const " (?accessibleRoot@QQuickWindow@@UBEPAVQAccessibleInterface@@XZ)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QObject * __thiscall QQuickWindow::focusObject(void)const " (?focusObject@QQuickWindow@@UBEPAVQObject@@XZ)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::exposeEvent(class QExposeEvent *)" (?exposeEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQExposeEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::focusInEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusInEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::focusOutEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusOutEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::showEvent(class QShowEvent *)" (?showEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQShowEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::hideEvent(class QHideEvent *)" (?hideEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQHideEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::keyPressEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyPressEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::keyReleaseEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyReleaseEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::mousePressEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mousePressEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::mouseReleaseEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseReleaseEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::mouseDoubleClickEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseDoubleClickEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickView::mouseMoveEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseMoveEvent@QQuickView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QQuickWindow::wheelEvent(class QWheelEvent *)" (?wheelEvent@QQuickWindow@@MAEXPAVQWheelEvent@@@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*thiscall QQuickView::~QQuickView(void)" (*_imp_??1QQuickView@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * _*thiscall QQuickView::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQQuickView@@UAEPAXI@Z)
>   mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QQmlDebuggingEnabler::QQmlDebuggingEnabler(bool)" (__imp_??0QQmlDebuggingEnabler@@QAE@_N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl`dynamic initializer for 'qmlEnableDebuggingHelper''(void)" (??*_EqmlEnableDebuggingHelper@@YAXXZ)
>   debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 24 unresolved externals
>   jom: E:\QtProjects\build-Test_QMLWidgets01-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\Test_QMLWidgets01.exe] Error 1120
>   jom: E:\QtProjects\build-Test_QMLWidgets01-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
>   15:16:30: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project Test_QMLWidgets01 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2010 32bit)
>   When executing step 'Make'
>   15:16:30: Elapsed time: 00:04.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read error messages. Seems that you don't link necessary Qt modules to your project.

Comment: And how do I have to link what?

Comment: Look help for your IDE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978471/qt-creator-add-qt-module-to-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you need to add to your `.pro` file:
`QT       += core gui widgets quick`

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I have installed Qt 5 but it seems that my Qt still has Qt4.8 and I have to manually add all files. Is there a way to automate this process or do it once for all.

Comment: @Jino, You can try to add another Kit to QtCreator.

Comment: @Kakadu, Can you tell me which Kit I should install and how. If you have steps to do that, please share that with me.

Comment: @Jino, you can start from http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html